# Weird Issue on 2008/2008R2 Shares using SMB2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, server-message-block

Having a very odd issue in which when connecting to shares from 2008 or 2008 R2 servers that are hosted by a 2008 or 2008 R2 server the files added to a folder will not always appear to update right away. However, this issue doesn't happen if the server hosting the share is running 2003 or has SMB2 turned off.

Here is a link with the same issue I'm having: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/4b69fe06-2b72-4795-a691-aa68aa348cb1/

I've tried everything there and found the issue seems to be directly related with SMB2. When I disable SMB2 the problem doesn't happen. However, I don't really consider this to be a real fix and so was hoping someone would have an idea to the cause and maybe a solution.

Comment: Fix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2778834
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646563

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a defect in the directory cache feature that was introduced with Windows Server 2008/SMB2.  There are three different caches utilized by the client SMB network redirector if SMB 2.0 is the negotiated protocol. File Information Cache, File Not Found Cache, and Directory Cache.

You may be able to localize this further by only disabling the directory cache on the client.

**SMB2 Client Redirector Caches Explained**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

You may want to try updating your mrxsmb20.sys on the client, although I would update all of the files in 2473205 on both the clients and the servers.

**"STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND" error message when you open a newly-created file in a shared folder in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2628582

**SMB2 directory cache is not updated correctly if a file is deleted in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646563

Most recent version:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2778834

Comment: After applying both (not one single fixed it), the problem went away. It has to be applied on the servers connecting to the share and not the server hosting the share.

Answer (score 1):

There really does seem to be a problem with SMBv2 in situations like this, and the way to go about resolving it is to disable it. This has certain side effects, like reports of BSODs when using network shares on the same server (such as in terminal environments) when accessed via older Microsoft software. It also impacts your ability to use Offline Files if your clients are Vista/7.

In any case, here's a great blog post about it, and the comments are pretty engaging as well with a lot of good links and cases of this occuring.

[http://laslow.net/2011/01/31/server-2008-r2-and-windows-7-client-smb2-share-refresh-issue/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120213122658/http://laslow.net/2011/01/31/server-2008-r2-and-windows-7-client-smb2-share-refresh-issue/)

Oh, and lastly.... here's a list of the available hotfixes regarding SMB for 2008 and 2008R2. None of them appear to be referencing the issue that you and others are experiencing.

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=2473205